# Chaining together multiple commands in bash shell

Tags: bash, shell, operating-system, return-value

I''m taking a C class, and every program written in C must return 0 if it was successfull.

Now imagine I have 3 programs written in C, doing whatever you like, but they are all successfull in what they make so they all return 0.

I have a question about how the OS handles this return value.

Think about chaining together these three commands in the Bash shell, executing the third if and only if the first two are successfull.

```
(command1 && command2) && command3
```

However if command1 and both command2 are successfull they both return 0, hence I cannot wrap my mind about how this mechanism works, since 0 and whatever makes always 0 (false).
So that command3 will not execute..(also command2 won't)

Thanks in advance

Comment: `(a && b) && c` is considerably less efficient than `a && b && c` or `{ a && b; } && c`. Only use the parenthesis if you intentionally desire an explicit subshell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rationale is that there is one way (`0`) for a command to succeed but many ways (any non-zero integer) for it to fail. Don't confuse bash's use of exit statuses with the standard Boolean interpretation of 0 as false and nonzero as true. The shell if statement checks if its command succeeds.

`&&` is not a boolean operator in the sense you are thinking. The exit status of `command1 && command2` is `0` (success) if both `command1` and `command2` have exit statuses of `0`. If `command1` has a non-zero (failure) exit status, that is the exit status of the compound command (and indeed, `command2` does not run at all). If `command1` succeeds, then `command2` executes and the exit status of the compound command is the exit status of `command2`.

Also remember to not confuse the compound command execution with the arithmetic execution operator `(( ... ))`, which is a special command whose contents are evaluated as an arithmetic expression, with an exit status of 0 if the expression has a non-zero value and an exit status of 1 if the expression equals 0. (Don't be tempted into thinking that `(( ... ))` is somehow equivalent to logical NOT, though.)

Answer (score -1):

You can use if statement.

```
if [ `command1` -eq 0 ] && [ `command2` -eq 0 ]; then command3; fi
```

Comment: This is comparing the _output_ of the commands to 0, not the _exit status_ of the commands.